# PHP | json_encode removes html tags

Tags: php, html, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I have a big multidimensional array to which there are multiple string values that contains strings with html tags and attributes.

but when i use `json_encode` the output i get has some of the tags being removed.

Here is the example i have tried on a separate file to be sure if this actually is the problem with json encode and turns out i was right.

```
<?php
$var = array(
    "type" => "<p style=\"text-align: center;\">sfds</p>"
);
   $encoded = json_encode($var);


echo '<pre>';
print_r($encoded);
```

How to handle this kind of situation??

this is the result i got from example.

```
{"type":"
sfds<\/p>"}
```

and this is the result i am getting from my multidimensional array.

```
{"data":[{"type":"columns","data":{"columns":[{"width":6,"blocks":[]},{"width":6,"blocks":[]}],"preset":"columns-6-6"}},{"type":"columns","data":{"columns":[{"width":6,"blocks":[{"type":"heading","data":{"text":"
I am the Heading<\/p>","mce_0":"

I am the Heading<\/p>"}},{"type":"heading","data":{"text":"

sfds<\/p>","mce_1":"

sfds<\/p>"}}]},{"width":6,"blocks":[{"type":"text","data":{"text":"

\n
Im Text<\/div>\n<\/div>","mce_2":"
\n
Im Text<\/div>\n<\/div>"}}]}],"preset":"columns-6-6"}},{"type":"text","data":{"text":"
\n
Im just a text<\/div>\n<\/div>","mce_3":"
\n
Im just a text<\/div>\n<\/div>"}}]}
```

=-=-=-=-=-=-

**Update:** Generated HTML source Code of the var_dump of array variable that i am trying to encode.

```
<pre> after set2_decode:<br>array(1) {
  ["data"]=&gt;
  array(3) {
    [0]=&gt;
    array(2) {
      ["type"]=&gt;
      string(7) "columns"
      ["data"]=&gt;
      array(2) {
        ["columns"]=&gt;
        array(2) {
          [0]=&gt;
          array(2) {
            ["width"]=&gt;
            int(6)
            ["blocks"]=&gt;
            array(0) {
            }
          }
          [1]=&gt;
          array(2) {
            ["width"]=&gt;
            int(6)
            ["blocks"]=&gt;
            array(0) {
            }
          }
        }
        ["preset"]=&gt;
        string(11) "columns-6-6"
      }
    }
    [1]=&gt;
    array(2) {
      ["type"]=&gt;
      string(7) "columns"
      ["data"]=&gt;
      array(2) {
        ["columns"]=&gt;
        array(2) {
          [0]=&gt;
          array(2) {
            ["width"]=&gt;
            int(6)
            ["blocks"]=&gt;
            array(2) {
              [0]=&gt;
              array(2) {
                ["type"]=&gt;
                string(7) "heading"
                ["data"]=&gt;
                array(2) {
                  ["text"]=&gt;
                  string(23) "<p>I am the Heading</p>"
                  ["mce_0"]=&gt;
                  string(23) "<p>I am the Heading</p>"
                }
              }
              [1]=&gt;
              array(2) {
                ["type"]=&gt;
                string(7) "heading"
                ["data"]=&gt;
                array(2) {
                  ["text"]=&gt;
                  string(39) "<p style="text-align: center;">sfds</p>"
                  ["mce_1"]=&gt;
                  string(39) "<p style="text-align: center;">sfds</p>"
                }
              }
            }
          }
          [1]=&gt;
          array(2) {
            ["width"]=&gt;
            int(6)
            ["blocks"]=&gt;
            array(1) {
              [0]=&gt;
              array(2) {
                ["type"]=&gt;
                string(4) "text"
                ["data"]=&gt;
                array(2) {
                  ["text"]=&gt;
                  string(59) "<div>
<div style="text-align: center;">Im Text</div>
</div>"
                  ["mce_2"]=&gt;
                  string(59) "<div>
<div style="text-align: center;">Im Text</div>
</div>"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
        ["preset"]=&gt;
        string(11) "columns-6-6"
      }
    }
    [2]=&gt;
    array(2) {
      ["type"]=&gt;
      string(4) "text"
      ["data"]=&gt;
      array(2) {
        ["text"]=&gt;
        string(65) "<div>
<div style="text-align: right;">Im just a text</div>
</div>"
        ["mce_3"]=&gt;
        string(65) "<div>
<div style="text-align: right;">Im just a text</div>
</div>"
      }
    }
  }
}
</pre>
```

Comment: Instead of seeing in a browser - open generated html. Or run script in a console.

Comment: @u_mulder
didnt got your point. what is the use of seeing the data in browser when the encoded json dosent work fine. i need the json, but that json should include the html tags also with attributes.

and i have tried on browser the array works fine and html tags cant be seen directly as its gets implemented when viewed in browser.

Comment: Please https://3v4l.org/XWI43

Comment: See source of generated json in your browser.

Comment: @u_mulder
Already done sir, i have pasted the quote in my question.

but how does this outputs wrong in my php.??

Comment: What is the problem with new output?

Comment: @u_mulder
ok. the link you gave i tried copy pasting my code back again to it. and it works fine over there. but on localhost(wamp) and http://www.phpcodepad.com/ my code dosent work. you can try copy pasting same code on phpcodepad :O_o

Comment: @u_mulder
is it the php version problem?

Comment: Please, open generated html on codepad. Please read answer of @Tropen. Please see this screenshot http://dl4.joxi.net/drive/2017/01/26/0018/0306/1204530/30/b34cc7feba.jpg.

Comment: @u_mulder
i got your point. Thanks.
 means json_decode is working fine? its just the browser cant show it in right format.

Answer (score 4):

Your browser hides all tags.
use [htmlentities()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) to see all tags

```
print_r(htmlentities($encoded));
```

Comment: htmlentities works for string nor multidimensional arrays.
so i tried like this.
`ob_start();
      print_r($set2_decode);
      $buffer = ob_get_clean();
      echo "<pre> after set2_decode = ".htmlentities($buffer)."</pre>";`

Answer (score 2):

I think htmlentities will help. Please use print_r and then escape your html.

```
echo htmlentities (print_r (json_encode($var), true));
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

it is not best practice  to put HTML in JSON response, the best practice is to accually build the html in frontend and just call the data in the  html already built. Howeever note that you cannot  have pure html in json response. it is usually escaped. So you have to make sure your html is properly built.
This is a good article to  help  you with that.

https://www.thorntech.com/2012/07/4-things-you-must-do-when-putting-html-in-json/